# Can $ \text{GL}^+(2, \mathbb{R}) $ be decomposed as a product of dilation, shear in x, shear in y, and rotation?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, group-theory

I'm investigating the structure of the group $ \text{GL}^+(2, \mathbb{R}) $ of invertible $ 2 \times 2 $ matrices with positive determinant. Specifically, I'd like to know if every matrix in $ \text{GL}^+(2, \mathbb{R}) $ can be uniquely represented as a product of:

1. A dilation matrix:
   $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   d & 0 \\
   0 & d \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
   where $ d > 0 $.
2. A shear matrix in the x-direction:
   $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & u \\
   0 & 1 \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
3. A shear matrix in the y-direction:
   $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   1 & 0 \\
   v & 1 \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$
4. A rotation matrix:
   $$
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\
   \sin \theta & \cos \theta \\
   \end{bmatrix}
   $$

Is every matrix in $ \text{GL}^+(2, \mathbb{R}) $ expressible in this manner? If such a decomposition is possible, can it be made unique for any given matrix in the group? If not, which matrices in $ \text{GL}^+(2, \mathbb{R}) $ defy this decomposition?

Any insights or references on this matter would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe the [Iwasawa decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iwasawa_decomposition) does what you want. In this case you only need a shear in either the $x$ or $y$ direction

Comment: My apologies, I didn't notice that you wanted the diagonal part to be scalar, so what I said doesn't work

Comment: @SamBallas Yes, I have flexibility only with replacing the shears with something else. I must keep the dilation (not scaling) and the rotation.

Comment: Presumably you are restricting to a particular order of matrices of the form (1), (2), (3), (4)?

Comment: @TravisWillse Yes this is fine.

Comment: I suspect squeeze matrices might do the trick instead of the shears:

$$
\begin{bmatrix} e^x & 0 \\ 0 & e^{-x} \end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} \cosh y & \sinh y \\ \sinh y & \cosh y \end{bmatrix}
$$

This is because exp A+X+B in 2D geometric metric algebra generates GL+(2,R). A is a scalar, X a vector and B a pseudo-scalar and represent dilation, squeezes and rotations, respectively.