# Is the combination of dilation, two squeezes, and a rotation a valid representation for any matrix in $\text{GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R})$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry, group-theory

I've been exploring different ways to represent matrices in $ \text{GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R}) $, the group of $ 2 \times 2 $ matrices with positive determinant. One decomposition I've come across involves a dilation, followed by two squeezes (hyperbolic rotations), and then a standard rotation:

1. **Dilation**:
   $$
   D(\lambda) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
   \lambda & 0 \\
   0 & \lambda \\
   \end{array} \right]
   $$
2. **Squeeze along x-direction**:
   $$
   S_x(x) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
   e^x & 0 \\
   0 & e^{-x} \\
   \end{array} \right]
   $$
3. **Squeeze along y-direction**:
   $$
   S_y(y) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
   \cosh(y) & \sinh(y) \\
   \sinh(y) & \cosh(y) \\
   \end{array} \right]
   $$
4. **Rotation**:
   $$
   R(\theta) = \left[ \begin{array}{cc}
   \cos(\theta) & -\sin(\theta) \\
   \sin(\theta) & \cos(\theta) \\
   \end{array} \right]
   $$

My question is: Can any matrix in $ \text{GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R}) $ be represented as a product of these four transformations? Specifically, is the combination:
$$
M = D(\lambda) \times S_x(x) \times S_y(y) \times R(\theta)
$$
sufficient to span the entirety of $ \text{GL}^+(2,\mathbb{R}) $? If not, what would be the limitations or missing components of this representation?

Comment: related https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4783171/188569